# Basic Objective C Code Problem

Tags: objective-c

In my grid class I have the constructor:

```
 - (id) init
{
    if ( self = [super init] )
    {

        isOccupied = NO;
        gridImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"grid.png"];


    }
    return self;
}
```

I set gridImage as a property.

In my viewController I have:

```
UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,200,200)];
[temp setImage: myGrid.gridImage];
[self.view addSubview: temp];
```

myGrid is an instance of the Grid Class...
but it doesn't display? when I directly enter the file name it works, but not when i use properties to access. Can anyone help please?

my grid header:

```
@interface Grid : NSObject {


//Locations *locations[20][20];
BOOL isOccupied;
UIImage *gridImage; 
//Locations *mergedlocations[20][20];   


}
@property (retain) UIImage *gridImage
```

;

Comment: What do you mean "when I directly enter the file name"? In the view controller or in the grid class?

Comment: in the view controller :) thanks for reply!

Comment: I haven't really toyed with objective C, but shouldn't `UIImage alloc` be in your `alloc` method?

Comment: @mathepic - no, the alloc is fine, he's instantiating a UIImage object in his constructor.

Comment: @John - in your view controller add this line after [temp setImage...       NSLog(@" Temp is %@",temp);  What does it tell you in the log?

Comment: Temp is <UIImageView: 0x144890; frame = (10 10; 200 200); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1448c0>>

Comment: @Mike but isn't `init` for _initializing_ not _allocation_?

Comment: @mathepic - init for initializing SELF.  It's very common (and necessary) to be able to allocate other objects in an initializer.  You do not actually implement the alloc method; you do so indirectly in the init method via [super init], which ultimately gets to NSObject's init, and that does it's own alloc.

Comment: @john - Are you seeing the view controller's view?  Try setting it's background color to something so you can be sure you VC's view is there:  in ViewController's viewDidLoad    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: hey mike thanks for your effort. This solved it: gridImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"grid.png"] retain]; However im not really sure why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you set the image this way using retain?

```
gridImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"grid.png"] retain];
```

Comment: It works! :))). Can you tell me what went wrong then? Thanks!

Comment: initWithContentsOfFile needs the absolute path to the file (I think)